# <p> element wrong color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some text in a `<p>` tag showing up black. I have added a css class called white that I have given to the element that should make it white.

Here is the inspection of the html once the page is displayed in a browser:

```
<p class="text-center vertical-center white">Center-aligned text.</p>
```

This is my css class:

```
.white {
    color: white;
}
```

This is the computed style of the element:

> color rgb(51, 51, 51)
>
> #333body (scaffolding.less 31)

I am not aware of what scaffolding.less is but I am using some libraries/frameworks such as angular 2 and bootstrap. Surely my class should override scaffolding.less?

Comment: Have you tried putting `.white {
    color: white !important;
}`

Comment: or use CSS specificity p.text-center.vertical-center.white { color: white }

Comment: No, it is not a given that your class should override the libraries. Your selector is very weak in terms of specificity as it has only one class selector. You may want to make it more specific. (Worst case use `!important` like mentioned in above comment but I won't recommend it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI now you can try to this Css with `p` `tag` and `class`

as like this

```
body p.white, .white{color:#fff;}
```

and if you are using only `.white` `class` for **color** **white** than you can used to this

```
.white{color: #ffffff !important;} // used only this if you have only change color
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should work without using !important. Just make sure you include your CSS file after all other framework CSS files. So your CSS overrides the framework CSS.